# how to make my method running on the template of google-app-engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, methods

the model is :

```
class someModel(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

    def name_is_sss(self):
        return self.name=='sss'
```

the view is :

```
    a=someModel()
    a.name='sss'
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.join('templates', 'blog/a.html'))
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {'a':a}))
```

and the html is :

```
{{ a.name_is_sss }}
```

the page shows :

```
True
```

so i want to make it more useful, and  like this:

the model:

```
class someModel(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

    def name_is_x(self,x):
        return self.name==x
```

the html is :

```
{% a.name_is_x 'www'%}
```

or

```
{{ a.name_is_x 'www'}}
```

but the error is :

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'a.name_is_x'
```

or

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder:  'www'
```

so  how to make my method running

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to enable a method in tamplate of google-app-engine..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842324/how-to-enable-a-method-in-tamplate-of-google-app-engine)

Comment: This is a duplicate of your other recent question -- delete this one and edit _that_ one to be more complete (as this one is)!  The answer given there is correct: you need to enable a more recent Django version than the default 0.96, it's just one import and one call you need to do in your `.py` file!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this already?

```
{{ a.name_is_x('www') }}
```